# Password reset is not enabled. Set the EnablePasswordReset property of the membership provider to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to reset current user pasword and get new password. I'm newbie. How do i solve this problem?

My code :

```
public static string ResetCurrentUserPassword(string userName)
{
    MembershipProvider p = (MembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["Default"];
    MembershipUser obj = Membership.GetUser(userName);
    return obj.ResetPassword();                          
}
```

Web.config :

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="SitefinitySiteMap">
    <providers>
        <add name="SitefinitySiteMap" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinitySiteMap, Telerik.Sitefinity" enablePasswordReset="true" taxonomyProvider="OpenAccessDataProvider" pageTaxonomy="Pages" rootNode="FrontendSiteMap" pageProvider="OpenAccessDataProvider"/>
    </providers>
</siteMap>
<roleManager enabled="false"/>
<membership defaultProvider="Default">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity"  enablePasswordReset="true"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following link: [Telerik EnablePasswordReset](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/resetting-administrator-password.html)

The important part is following:

There are two properties of the membership provider that should also be changed in the web.config file. The enablePasswordReset should be set to true, and the requiresQuestionAndAnswer to false.

I think you have to enhance your web.config with the following Parameter:

```
<add name="Default" enablePasswordReset="true" .....
```

gretz noone

Comment: try to restart your IIS Service:
cmd -> resetiis

Comment: be sure that you edited the right web.config i.e.:
if you are running your own Website follow the path in the IIS Settings for exapmle: "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\[yourapplicationnname]\web.config" then reset your IIS and it should work. 
be sure that you edited the write XML-tree: "<membership " is the right one.
I dont have any more thoughts :) iam sorry. maybe you should ask in the telerik Forum for help (admins are answering rly fast there).